# Library not found for LottieReactNative

Tags: xcode, react-native

I have such error in Xcode in react native project, lottie-react-native is installed in the project and linked, however, Xcode still doesn't see this library. Any ideas how is possible to solve that issue?

[image]

lottie-react-native is already linked:

[image]

Comment: react-native link sometimes doesn't link all files correctly. You can verify the linking process is complete or not by checking the readme or documentation of the project and cross checking the manual linking section with the files in your project and see if all the files have the necessary lines of code added to them and if not, you can add them manually.

Comment: @HishamMubarak which exactly files should I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem's to me like you have not linked your package with your project.
After installing NPM packages or any packages that requires native integration, you need to integrate them before you can start using it.

Below linked documentation will help you on easy command line linking.
http://airbnb.io/lottie/react-native/react-native.html#ios
http://airbnb.io/lottie/react-native/react-native.html#android

If command line linking doesn't work, or if app shows linking error even after entering the command line link, you can see the manual linking process in the linked documentation and cross check it with your project files.
http://airbnb.io/lottie/react-native/react-native.html

Comment: It seems that your solution works, I have cleaned Xcode project and rebuild it once again and that error dissapeared, it seems like it was problems with react-native link